# Automatically use appropriate Python version with Jedi.el

Tags: python, jedi

[Documentation](http://tkf.github.io/emacs-jedi/latest/#automatically-use-appropriate-python-version) says that it can be done by making some variables buffer local. But how to make it correctly?

Can somebody show me example how to configure this `jedi.el` behaviour correctly?

Now I have two virtualenv with installed jedi for python 2 and 3. When I change working virtualenv or python buffer, I'll check current python version and if it has changed i call [this function](https://gitlab.com/cryptomaniac/emacs.d/blob/master/my-conf/functions.el#L40)

```
(defun cm:jedi-setup-server ()
  "Setup Jedi server, update and reload."
  (interactive)
  (if (not (equal python-environment-default-root-name (cm:jedi-environment-root-name)))
      (progn
        (custom-set-variables
         '(python-environment-default-root-name (cm:jedi-environment-root-name))
         '(jedi:server-command
           (concat (venv-name-to-dir (cm:jedi-environment-root-name)) "bin/jediepcserver")))
        (jedi:install-server-block))))
```

Comment: Quiestion updated